# Start writing to a new XML File each week, PHP

Tags: php

I have a form which, when submitted, writes the inputted data to an XML file. As the form continues to be submitted, the data appends the XML file which works perfect. My problem is I need to start writing to a new XML file each week, does anyone have any ideas as to how I would achieve this? I am writing in PHP. I was thinking something along the lines of;

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 week"));
```

I also have a file creation date, but this is in ISODate format so I need to figure out how to single out the date section without the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include the week number in the filename. When writing check if the file exists, if not make a new xml file:

```
$filename = date('Y-W').'.xml'; //2014-26.xml

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    //append data to xml file
} else {
    //create new xml file for the new week
}
```

Comment: I am just heading home now so I will try this in the morning, but it sounds promising. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using a cron job for the task?

Example. Make a text file containing.

```
0 8 * * Sat <username> <command>
```

This would be a cronjob that would run at 8:00 am every Sat. If you still want to do it in php set the command to a php file that appends the xml. Like so.

```
0 8 * * Sat <username> php append.php
```

To add the job navigate to your file and run

```
crontab <filename>
```

http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

Comment: The thought crossed my mind but wasnt sure if it would be suitable, ill try that thanks!